# Capturing the comment and URL when Like is clicked

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-like, capture

I'm capturing the click of the Like button on my site by subscribing to the edge.create event for the button.  This works fine but I'm wondering if there's also a way, while I'm at it, to capture the comment that the user enters when they post the Like to their Facebook, and maybe also get the URL of their Facebook page.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get to the comment would be to query the Graph API and that requires both an application and the user granting your app permissions.

Comment: Hmmm.  That doesn't sound too practical.  How about getting the URL of their Facebook page and then maybe I could just go there and see what appeared?

Comment: Are you talking about screen scraping?  I'm not sure how friendly Facebook is to that technique.  You should have your attorney review the TOS and Policies for facebook.

Comment: No.  I'd just like to get the URL of their Facebook page, like http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100003070826083&sk=wall - the place that Facebook put the comment when the user clicked the Like button.

Comment: Wait, first you want to "capture a comment" and now you just want to go to their profile, even though it is not public.  You will need to do an app and ask the user for permissions.

Comment: I just want to see what they wrote about my site.  If there's no way to do that without getting their permission, I won't do it.  Not a big deal  Thanks.